# Hide profile fields when not populated

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface

I have edited [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194674/stackoverflow) and removed some fields like email, website, real name and age. They are shown blank when I see my profile. but when they are empty why does Stack Exchange show them?

Can we show only the fields which has data?

> [image]

Comment: I guess my question for you is why is this a problem?  Would you rather see the missing fields or a big white space below the last field that is populated?

Comment: Can you link to a profile that shows a different amount of fields?

Comment: FYI - Your real name and email are never displayed publicly and only available to you and the moderators.  So those fields are always hidden, it is just age, location, and website that are displayed

Comment: @DuncanJones http://stackoverflow.com/users/1838341/dd see the field count is less

Comment: @psubsee2003 i got u point

Comment: why downvote..?

Comment: I think @psubsee2003 has explained your problem - you only see more fields because the profile is your own. When I examine your profile and the one you linked, they are identical in size.

Comment: @psubsee2003 but when the fields are empty why to show them

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW On meta, people down-vote when they don't like a proposal. It doesn't have the same negative connotations that you associated with downvotes on the non-meta sites.

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW why not?  (see my first [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201853/why-the-profile-information-field-are-present-when-they-are-empty?noredirect=1#comment640995_201853))

Comment: see qus Why the profile information field are present when they are empty

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW you still haven't supported your position that they should be hidden if empty.  If you want to change something you need to come up with an argument.  So if you think they should be hidden when empty, please explain why

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW But I think the answer here is to show you that the fields are there.  I'd rather see the empty fields than have to make the developers worry about proper spacing in the various combinations of missing fields

Comment: why so downvoting..is there any wrong in qus

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW [Duncan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201853/why-is-this-a-problem-would-you-rather-see-the-missing-fields-or-a-big-white-sp#comment641005_201853) partially answered that before.  You are effectively asking for a feature to hide fields from the profile and some people might be downvoting because they disagree.  Similarly, your "feature request" is very incomplete because you are just saying "hide these fields when empty" rather than giving a good reason why they should be hidden.

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW Voting on meta works somewhat different than on the main site. People vote here based on how they 'like' a certain idea or if they agree that something is a problem or not. People don't seem to see this as a real problem/don't seem to like the feature request.

Comment: Why did you copy/paste psubsee2003's comment into the title? It makes no sense now because it was a question addressed to you.

Comment: Though I feel the empty fields are ugly, I don't really care and I'd rather have time spent on other features. But still then, I also don't understand why people would downvote this. I assume in this case a downvote either means that people think the post is not useful (I feel even in the first revision the intention was quite clear; details aside) or that people actually *dislike* such change (but then what's the problem when this would be implemented)? In both cases I don't really understand the downvotes, and I'd *almost* cast a pity upvote. In short: voters, care to explain?

Comment: @Arjan I haven't voted but the reason I considered downvoting is because the feature request seems like a "I don't like this, change it" request without any real reasoning behind the request.  I think feature requests, in general, should provide a little more meat to explain why it would be beneficial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Between what you mention in your comments and the body of your updated post, you really have 2 questions.

**Why are "some" profiles different than others?**

The answer there is there are 2 main views for each profile, a public one and a private one.  Personal information, like email addresses and full names are hidden from view in the public profile, but are in the private view of the profile where only yourself and moderators (and the Stack Exchange team) can access.  The "Missing" fields you are seeing when comparing other profiles to yours aren't hidden because they are empty, they are hidden because they are not available publicly.

**Why aren't empty fields hidden?**

The best answer to this question is somewhat of a question back at you, "why not".  Is there a good reason to hide empty fields from either the public or private profile?

My take is this was a design decision to make the profile page easier to design.  You only have 2 layouts instead of a dozen or more based on every possible variation of completed vs empty field.  Additionally, it could partially be there to show you what information you can provide.

In the end, I think they could be hidden if there is a compelling reason to hide them, but given the fact that there are [hundreds of good (and popular)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined?sort=votes&pageSize=50) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) out there, this seems to be a waste of time.

In fact the only fields that do show up are the fields in which you can fill in the blank yourself.  Fields that are generated by the system (like how long you've been a member, or when you were last seen) as always populated.

Just a side note, there are 2 system populated fields that are hidden when there is no data in the private view of your profile.  The fields for  "Helpful Flags" and "Recent Names" only show up when the value is >0.  But these were added after the profile page was designed and since they are at the end, I'm guessing it was easier to hide when there is nothing to show.